# return tuples with maximum values in one field when there is a tie

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql table like:

```
Name  | Value
------+------
Andy  | 22
Ben   | 22
Carl  | 22
David | 21
Eddie | 20
Frank | 19
```

I need an sql query that will return the tuples containing the maximum value, and if there is a tie (as in the example above), the relevant tuples in the tie will all need to be returned. Note that the values are already in descending order, and if there is no tie, one tuple is returned.

I have tried TOP and MAX in conjunction with GROUP BYs, but none of these are working.

TOP returns an error for invalid syntax and my attempts with MAX are flat out wrong.

In the above example, the tuples with Andy, Ben and Carl should be returned.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Done - I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention `TOP` which suggests SQL Server.  If so, you can use `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by value desc;
```

Alas, that won't work in Postgres.  Just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value = (select max(t2.value) from t);
```

Comment: I'm using postgresql - I don't think TOP works with it - I'm getting "syntax error at or near with"

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use window function `rank()`:

```
select name, value
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(order by value desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The subquery ranks records per descending `value`; records that have the same value get the same rank. Then, the outer query filters on the top record(s).